# apt-get broken on kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, kubuntu

I just wanted to add my little stone, so I tried to do an install of "wine" on a Kubuntu installed on my laptop (amd64 quad proc, 12.04, strictly and regularly updated and maintained) which leads directly to a load of apt problems.

In addition, I have now 4 different instances of graphics apps for package/software maintenance, all in submenu K/system : software update, muon software manager, Ubuntu software center, muon update manager. In addition, I still have a broken apt system, I don't understand from what...

I followed the instructions given on that other thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/983543, shortened to :

> dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
>
> dpkg --configure -a

This gave me the final result :

```
dpkg : des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de wine1.4-common :  wine1.4-common dépend de wine1.4 (=
1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ; cependant :   Le paquet wine1.4 n'est pas installé. dpkg : erreur de traitement de wine1.4-common (--configure) : 
problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré dpkg : des problèmes
de dépendances empêchent la configuration de wine1.4-amd64 : 
wine1.4-amd64 dépend de wine1.4-common (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ;
cependant :  Le paquet wine1.4-common n'est pas encore configuré. 
dpkg : erreur de traitement de wine1.4-amd64 (--configure) : 
problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré Paramétrage de
libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1) ... Paramétrage de
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3) ... Traitement des actions
différées (« triggers ») pour « libc-bin »... ldconfig deferred
processing now taking place Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant
l'exécution :  wine1.4-common  wine1.4-amd64
```

I am still searching for a solution, also to simplify those duplicate graphic apps for software management, would appreciate any help, thanks !

Comment: Check the dependencies. From what I can get from your error message is that you need libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and libdrm-intel1:i386. Seems strange that you need 386 packages for an amd64 packa as well.

Comment: hi mcNisse thanks anyways i have forgotten wine, too much troubble, i'll just stick to virtualbox it finnaly gives good results for my needs. I suppose it wanted i386 in order to run i386 windows libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

try

> `sudo dpkg --configure -a

Maybe this solves your problem. `

Comment: hias you may notice i did it (i am working as root so do not use the "sudo" )

Comment: the message given in return by dpkg is in french. it means something like "unmet dependancies while installing wine-1.4-common"

Comment: hi again, i finnaly solved the wine blocking problem, i just ran : [code] #dpkg --purge wine* [/code] followed by an [code] #apt-get -f install [/code] and everything went back to normal, now i would like to simplify the menu and remove the duplicate muon/update manager from k/system menu wich i hope will be easy

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for the dependency resolution can be, that via
additional sources or manual installation some problematic are installed.
Especially problematic if some kind of *newer* packages are installed, that are not part of the currently configured package repositories.

This could be the result of the `dpkg -i
/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` command your have invoked.

On way to work around this problem is to try to remove more and more packages with the following commands

```
dpkg --force-depends --purge <PackageNameList>
apt-get install --fix-broken
```

- `dpkg --force-depends --purge` will remove the package even if another package depends on the installation of this package.
- `apt-get install --fix-broken` will try to get the system in a  consistent state by installing all missing dependencies.

You should start with *wine1.4-common* and extend the
*PackageNameList* with all other noted packages on the output of `dpkg
--configure -a`

#### Postscriptum

```
export   LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export   LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

Afterwards the error message should be readable also on the other side of the Rhine ;-)